# How do I rename all files from folder to xxx{incremental}.jpg using command prompt

Tags: powershell, batch-file, command-line, windows-administration

I have below files in folder with a same name. Only the extensions are different. All files are valid jpg but with the wrong extension.

[image]

How to rename them with extension as .jpg, with a different prefix?

`ren *.* *.jpg` ----> Is not working for me as they all are having same prefix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
Clear-Host
$directoryPath = "C:\directory\with\images"
#Getting all files with "1.*" from $directoryPath
$foldercontent = Get-ChildItem -Path $directoryPath -Filter "1.*" | Where-Object { ! $_.PSIsContainer }
foreach($item in $foldercontent) {
    Move-Item -Path $item.FullName -Destination "$directoryPath\image$($item.Extension).jpg"
}
```

File names will be:

```
image.J84.jpg
image.J85.jpg
```

Comment: Can it be doable with command prompt.?

Comment: @SameerPatkar Yes, it works in powershell. Use one-line `$foldercontent = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\tmp" -Filter "1.*" | Where-Object { ! $_.PSIsContainer }; foreach($item in $foldercontent) { Move-Item -Path $item.FullName -Destination "C:\tmp\image$($item.Extension).jpg" };`

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `ForFiles` utility for such a task, in the Command Prompt, PowerShell Prompt, or from a batch file.

```sh
forfiles /p "C:\directory\with\images" /m "1.*" /c "cmd /c ren @file image.@ext.jpg"
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be used the following batch file to rename a file like `1.J73` to `image_73.jpg`:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "ImageFolder=C:\directory\with\images"
for /F "tokens=2 delims=Jj." %%I in ('dir "%ImageFolder%\1.J*" /A-D /B 2^>nul') do ren "%ImageFolder%\1.J%%I" "image_%%I.jpg"
endlocal
```

There is executed in background one more command process with the command line:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c dir "C:\directory\with\images\1.J*" /A-D /B 2>nul
```

**DIR** searches in the specified directory for

- just files because of the option `/A-D` (attribute not directory)
- matching the wildcard pattern `1.J*` and
- outputs just the names of the found files without path in bare format because of the option `/B` to the handle **STDOUT** (standard output) of the background command process.

**DIR** would output an error message to handle **STDERR** (standard error) on not finding any matching file. This error message is suppressed by redirecting it to the device **NUL** using `2>nul`.

Read the Microsoft documentation about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `dir` command line with using a separate command process started in background.

The output of **DIR** to **STDOUT** is captured by the Windows command processor `cmd.exe` processing the batch file and processed line by line after started `cmd.exe` closed itself.

**FOR** with option `/F` ignores empty lines which do not occur here. A non-empty line would be split up by default into substrings using normal space and horizontal tab as string delimiters. There would be checked next the first character of the first substring on being a semicolon which is by default the end of line character in which case the line would be ignored for further processing. Otherwise the first substring is assigned to the specified loop variable and the commands in body of the **FOR** loop are executed by `cmd.exe`.

The default behavior on line processing is modified by the used options `tokens=2` and `delims=Jj.`. The string delimiters are redefined with `J` and `j` and `.` which means a file name like `1.J73` is split up into the two substrings `1` and `73`. The option `tokens=2` instructs **FOR** to assign the second substring (token) to the specified loop variable `I`. The default `eol=;` is kept as the first substring is always `1` in this case and therefore no file name is ignored here. So for a file with name `1.J73` or `1.j73` the string `73` is assigned to the loop variable `I`.

Then the rename command **REN** is executed with the fully qualified file name of the current file and the new file name with the prefix `image_` and file number from existing file name and with the file extension `.jpg`. So the file is renamed from `1.J73` to `image_73.jpg` if there is not already a file with name `image_73.jpg` and the file to rename is not currently opened by an application in a manner which prevents renaming the file while being opened by the application.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `cmd /?`
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `ren /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`